# AlarmManager setRepeating function not working.

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I am trying to use `setRepeating` alarm, but it is not working for me. When I try to use the one time alarm then it is working for me.
Below is the code, please help me out where I am doing it wrong.

```
Toast.makeText(AndroidAlarmService.this, "Start Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Intent myIntent = new Intent(AndroidAlarmService.this, MyAlarmService.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(AndroidAlarmService.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

//alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
calendar.getTimeInMillis() , 10, pendingIntent);
System.out.println("Calendar"+calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

Thanks,
Aman

Answer (score 0):

We have to use RTC or RTC_Wakeup if we are using calendar.

Answer (score 0):

You have different frame of references in your `setRepeating()` method:

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(**AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP**, **calendar.getTimeInMillis()** , 10, pendingIntent);
```

AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME docs:

`alarm clock in SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`

AlarmManager.RTC docs:

`alarm clock in Sustem.currentTimeMillis()`

So both

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() , 10, pendingIntent);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() , 10, pendingIntent);
```

The same for *_WAKEUP types